# Find the x and y cordinates of users location

Tags: objective-c

I have a an image that i want to be to the right of the users location, how do I go about doing that? Is there a way to get the x and y coordinate of the users location and then take that and subtract the x and y of the image to make sure its always on the right?

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    region.center = worldView.userLocation.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  = 5;
    span.longitudeDelta = 5;
    region.span = span;
    [worldView setRegion:region animated:YES];

    UIImage *commentBox = [UIImage imageNamed:@"comment-box"];
    UIImageView *commentBoxImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:commentBox];
    [self.view addSubview:commentBoxImageView];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to make this image an annotation view. That is something that belongs to the map view - the map will draw the annotation view and will keep it at its coordinate as the map scrolls or the region changes. Now all you have to do is keep watching the user's coordinate and make sure the annotation is to the east of that.